# Broken built tools in android SDK manager (missing aapt.exe )

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, compiler-errors, build-tools

I am using eclipse from a couple months and it was working fine until Avast antivirus alerts me that  
appt.exe in sdk built-tools is not a secure program. I did not delete it but it seems like Avast  deleted it automatically!

Now Eclipse is throwing this error:
[image]

I opened my SDK manager and it shows a broken build-tools
[image: sdk manager]

What is the best thing to do in this case without affecting the rest of resources?
Is it recommended to uninstall the build-tools then install them?
I know this might seem as an easy problem but a small mistake might cause losing the whole projects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to reinstall `Broken Build-Tools Package, revision 21.0.2`

1. Select `Broken Build-Tools Package, revision 21.0.2`
2. Click on Uninstall button `Right-Bottom side`

Restart SDK Manager
Now, `Broken Build-Tools Package, revision 21.0.2` will be available to install.

1. Select `Andoird Build-Tools` of particular revision
2. Click on Install button `Right-Bottom side`